# Include a valid field if ModelState state is Invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-web-api, modelstate

In ASP.NET Web API I want to include a valid field when returning errors to the caller.

```
public class User 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ThirdPartyID is required!")]
    public int ThirdPartyID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Firstname is required!")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lastname is required!")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

When the caller posts a user with the ThirdParyID set, and the Firstname set, but without the Lastname, I want to add the ThirdPartyID to the response. I am using the below for Model Validation.

```
public class ModelValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I can set on the User to indicate that the ThirdPartyID should always be included in the returned error messages?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your business requirement. Is ThirdPartyId required or isn't it?

Comment: We can say it is. But I still want to return it in the error message even if it is sent by the consumer of the API during the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ModelState.AddModelError method.

```
ModelState.AddModelError("VariableName", "Error Message");
```

Comment: That's fine if I'm doing validation inside the controller, but I want to do it in ModelValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute and for different models the valid field I want to return will vary.